# Excel CONCATNATE with dates

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel with a large amount of rows.  I'm trying to concatenate text along with a date like 12/31/73.  I'm getting a string of numbers where the date is for some reason. This is what I've tried.

```
=CONCATENATE("Item removed on ",G2)
```

This is the output: "Item removed on 27029"
This is what I need: "Item removed on 12/31/73"

Comment: ="Item removed on "&TEXT(G2;"mm/dd/JJJJ/yy")

Comment: @WeAreOne -I got an error when I tried your suggestion so I tried this and still got and error. =CONCATENATE("Item removed on ",&TEXT(G2;"mm/dd/yy")

Comment: mm/dd/yy means Month Day Year. It depends on the language of your computer. Different languages, different letters to use. You can check the normal Numberformat of a date. Mark cell, Format cells, Numberformat, Custom, there you see the letters for your date in my Excel I need to use TT.MM.JJJJ for example

Comment: also no need to use the & when you use the concatenate function, use either & or concatenate means: only use this, nothing else: ="Item removed on "&TEXT(G2;"mm/dd/JJJJ/yy") or =CONCATENATE("Item removed on ",TEXT(G2;"mm/dd/yy")

Comment: Error might be cause of argument separator you use. Try this ="Item removed on "&TEXT(G2,"mm/dd/yy") (comma instead of semicolon)

Comment: In Europe we use semicolon as argument separator, in US you might use comma.

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores dates as numbers.  To convert from the date to a string, use the text function.  To get the format you show here, use text(G2,"mm/dd/yy") or text(G2, "m/d/yy") if you don't want leading zeroes.

A chart of the available formats is included here: https://exceljet.net/formulas/convert-date-to-text.